# Is it possible for someone to run JavaScript by typing it in an input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

This isn't something I really want to do, just wondering if it's possible.

Say I have a page like this, which is just a heading and an input box.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>2014-4-24-01</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function jQuerySetup() {
    if($) {

        $(document).ready( function () {

            $("body").on("keypress", "input", function ( event ){

                if(event.keyCode == 13){

                    $("body").get(0).innerHTML = this.value;

                }

            });

        });

    } else {

        window.setTimeout(jQuerySetup, 250);

    }

}

jQuerySetup();                  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Test</h3>
<input type="text" width="20">
<div id="testDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I type the following into the input box and hit enter, nothing happens. Why is that?

```
<script>window.setTimeout(function () { alert("Uh oh"); }, 1000);</script>
```

EDIT: And I know that it's very easy for someone to run JavaScript through the console window and achieve a similar effect. But my question is more of understanding why the above isn't possible (or why I'm not getting it right).

Comment: You are looking for evil, sorry, `eval()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run script from an input box using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). The way you are doing it won't work since the [specification states](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0) that scripts inserted via `.innerHTML` should not be executed (it's a large green note at the end of the section).

Comment: Thanks for the reference, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` won't execute the script, use jQuery `html` instead.

```
$("body").html(this.value);
```

Comment: @A.Wolff Here: http://jsfiddle.net/j9r6z/ Just put the following in the text box and press enter: `<script>window.setTimeout(function () { alert("Uh oh"); }, 1000);</script>`

Answer (score 0):

From the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0)...

> Note: script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted.

Instead just use `eval`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `if($) {` and `setTimeout` because it's handled by `$(document).ready`.

You can try that:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("body").on("keypress", "input", function ( event ){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("body").get(0).innerHTML = this.value;   
        } 
    });    
});
</script>
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/roshiro/teqWX/)

Comment: But how can $(document).ready work correctly if jQuery hasn't loaded yet?

Comment: You need to make sure your code jquery is loaded first.

By putting `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` first does the job.

Comment: To be honest I never seen anybody checking `if($) {` or setting timeout to start executing the jQuery

Comment: You may be right. I was used to using jQuery on other sites to play around with them, and in that case you need to wait until it loads. But if it's part of the html you probably don't. Thanks.